# Compare list of datetimes with datetime in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of datetime objects and would like to find the ones which are within a certain time frame:

```
import datetime

dates = [ datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 2, 0, 1),
          datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 3, 0, 2),
          datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 4, 0, 3),
          datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 5, 0, 4),
          datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 6, 0, 5),
          datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 7, 0, 6) ]
#in reality this is a list of over 25000 dates

mask = (dates>datetime.datetime(2007,1,3)) & \
       (dates<datetime.datetime(2007,1,6))
```

However, this results in the following error:
"TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to list"

How can I fix my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: deleting list elements based on condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623715/python-deleting-list-elements-based-on-condition)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your `dates` list is in sorted order, you can use  the [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html):

```
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect_right(dates, datetime.datetime(2007,1,3))
1
>>> bisect.bisect_left(dates, datetime.datetime(2007,1,6))
4
```

The `.bisect_*` functions return indices into the `dates` list:

```
>>> lower = bisect.bisect_right(dates, datetime.datetime(2007,1,3))
>>> upper = bisect.bisect_left(dates, datetime.datetime(2007,1,6))
>>> mask = dates[lower:upper]
>>> mask
[datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 3, 0, 2), datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 4, 0, 3), datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 5, 0, 4)]
```

Comment: I would disagree with you: doesn't bisect_left include the element in argument if it is present in the list ?

Comment: @Boud: That's the point of using `bisect`, it's to find the range of datetime objects that fall between the two values. Or do you mean it inserts it into the list? No, it doesn't do that, it simply returns the insertion point; use `insort_*()` to do that.

Comment: OP is asking for strict inequality

Comment: @Boud: it's easy enough to adjust from `_left` to `_right` in that case. I've done so in my update.

Comment: You were right, it is the fastest method (2.48 us per loop)! Thank you!

Comment: this required the list to be sorted though... ?

Comment: @InbarRose: indeed, unfortunatly the sorting requires a lot of time additionally

Answer (score 12):

You can mask a [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) in the syntax you describe *(but not a list)*:

```
import numpy as np

date1 = np.array(dates)
mask = (dates1 > datetime.datetime(2007,1,3)) & \
       (dates1 < datetime.datetime(2007,1,6))

In [14]: mask
Out[14]: array([False,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [15]: dates1[mask]
Out[15]: array([2007-01-03 00:02:00, 2007-01-04 00:03:00, 2007-01-05 00:04:00], dtype=object)
```

*(since this question is tagged numpy, presumably this is what you were intending.)*

Comment: The conversion np.array(dates) of my list of datetime objects to the numpy array takes almost 1 second....is there a faster conversion, since I have to do this repetitively?

Comment: don't start with a list, what do you have before that? 1s sounds long. I think worth looking into [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for efficient datetime arrays. (`pd.to_datetime(dates)`)

Comment: I wonder  if there is two period time I need to find in a array. How do I merge the mask?

Answer (score 5):

```
import datetime

dates = [ datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 2, 0, 1),
          datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 3, 0, 2),
          datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 4, 0, 3),
          datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 5, 0, 4),
          datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 6, 0, 5),
          datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 7, 0, 6) ]


within = [date for date in dates if datetime.datetime(2007,1,3) < date < datetime.datetime(2007,1,6)]
```

yields:

```
[datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 3, 0, 2), 
 datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 4, 0, 3), 
 datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 5, 0, 4)]
```

Comment: This is even faster (7.82 us per loop), than turning it into a numpy array (approach from hayden) (122 us per loop)

Comment: @HyperCube: I bet using `bisect` on a sorted list is even faster though. `bisect` does not traverse the whole list, it's methods bounded by O(log n) complexity, while this answer requires you to access the whole list (O(n) complexity).

Comment: However, I need the position in the list.
@MartijnPieters: I will try this out next ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - also bisect requires a sorted list.

Comment: @InbarRose: indeed, as I stated in my answer. :-)

Comment: yes - but you need to sort it before bisect - depending on the list, it might be faster to use this method, no?

Comment: Is it possible with this method to get the positions of the matching list entries? I could not figure it out yet.