# Compare and delete lists from a list of lists using max condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, sorting

I have a list of lists like this:

```
a=[['2012-05-11','yes','44','426.24'],['2013-03-22','no','12','426.24'],['2018-08-13','yes','88','426.24'] ,['2017-05-11','yes','404','450.24']]
```

I want to delete all the lists that have the same 4th value `( a[0][3],a[1][3] ...)` and only let the list that have the most recent date,
so in my case I want this result:

```
a=[['2018-08-13','yes','88','426.24'] ,['2017-05-11','yes','404','450.24']]
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting list elements based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623715/deleting-list-elements-based-on-condition)

Comment: @Shubham, this is not a duplicate

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Sorry, I mis read the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible via a combination of `itertools.groupby` and `sorted`.

The below solution explicitly uses `datetime` conversion for sorting dates.

After sorting, you only need to extract the final element of each `groupby` element for the required entry.

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

sorter = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[3], datetime.strptime(x[0], '%Y-%m-%d')))
grouper = groupby(sorter, key=itemgetter(3))

res = [list(j)[-1] for _, j in grouper]

[['2018-08-13', 'yes', '88', '426.24'],
 ['2017-05-11', 'yes', '404', '450.24']]
```

Comment: @Kasramvd, thanks - I also provided another answer (I don't need the rep, but it's interesting to see what community prefers).

Answer (score 3):

As an optimized way from both memory usage and runtime point of view, you can loop over your sub lists and just keep track of those that have a greater date. And since you want to do this for lists with duplicate last item a dictionary with that last item as the key is the best data structure you can use.

```
In [2]: from datetime import datetime

In [3]: def filter_func(arr):
   ...:     _container = {}
   ...:     for dt, *mid, last in arr:
   ...:         date_obj = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
   ...:         try:
   ...:             d = _container[last][0]
   ...:             if date_obj > d:
   ...:                  _container[last] = (date_obj, [dt] + mid)
   ...:         except KeyError:
   ...:             _container[last] = (date_obj, [dt] + mid)
   ...:     return [[*rest, last] for last, (_, rest) in _container.items()]
```

Demo:

```
In [5]: filter_func(a)
Out[5]: [['2018-08-13', 'yes', '88', '426.24'], ['2017-05-11', 'yes', '404', '450.24']]
```

Answer (score 2):

I will provide an solution without using any libraries.

First of all, you need to group the items by last field.

```
dict = {}
for elem in a:
   if elem[-1] not in dict:
      dict[elem[-1]] = []
   dict[elem[-1]].append(elem[:-1])

print(dict)

{'426.24': [['2012-05-11', 'yes', '44'], ['2013-03-22', 'no', '12'], ['2018-08-13', 'yes', '88']], '450.24': [['2017-05-11', 'yes', '404']]}
```

Then keep only the last item for every key in the **dictionary**.

```
for key in dict:
    dict[key] = sorted([elem[0] for elem in dict[key]], key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    dict[key] = dict[key].pop()
```

Then just use a `list comprehension` in order to filter initial array.

```
a = [elem for elem in a if elem[0] == dict[elem[-1]]]
```

Output

```
[['2018-08-13', 'yes', '88', '426.24'], ['2017-05-11', 'yes', '404', '450.24']]
```

Comment: Why don't use use `collections.defaultdict()` for grouping the items?

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution using `collections.defaultdict`. The idea is to restructure your dictionary by a key. Then use `max` with a custom `key` argument to extract the required result.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for *data, key in a:
    d[key].append(data)

res = [max(v, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], '%Y-%m-%d'))+[k]
       for k, v in d.items()]

[['2018-08-13', 'yes', '88', '426.24'],
 ['2017-05-11', 'yes', '404', '450.24']]
```

Comment: So much better but still there are rooms for improvement ;)) to do it with two separate loops. One for creating the dictionary and another for creating the expected array from dictionary (which might not be necessary tho).

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with the same idea as @Kasramvd but with easier-to-understand code (should make the idea more clear for less experienced Python programmers):

```
from datetime import datetime

def myfilter (arr):
    results = dict()

    for item in arr:
        index = item[3]
        if index not in results or datetime.strptime(item[0], '%Y-%m-%d') > datetime.strptime(results[index][0], '%Y-%m-%d'):
            results[index] = item

    print([item for _, item in results.items()])
```