# Filter elements from a list instance (or object) in a single expression

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

While using `os.walk` which needs me to alter the generated list of directories in order to filter them I wonder whether there is a nice way to do it:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for excl in EXCLUDES:
        if excl in dirs:
            dirs.remove(excl)
```

I know I can [generate a new `dirs` with list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623715/deleting-list-elements-based-on-condition) like `[e for e in dirs if e not in EXCLUDES]` but this would not work when I need to modify the *original instance*.

Writing s.th. like `[dirs.remove(e) for e in dirs if e in EXCLUDES]` *does work* but I'm abusing list comprehension - `pylint` does not like it (for a reason) and future versions of Python might even omit this expression because generated values are not used.

So in the provided scenario - is there a way to operate on a list like

```
dirs.remove_items(e for e in EXCLUDES if e in dirs)
```

Or more generally: is there a (recommended) way to run a command in a "for each" semantic, like

```
fn(e) for e in container
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this just fine with a `list` comprehension, you just use empty slice assignment to replace the *contents* of the original `dirs`:

```
dirs[:] = [e for e in dirs if e not in EXCLUDES]
#   ^^^ Replaces contents       ^^^ flip condition so you only keep not-excluded
```

This doesn't violate any rules of proper listcomp use; the listcomp has no side-effects, it just produces a new `list`, which you then use to replace the original contents of `dirs` in bulk.

Aside from that, to your question, "is there a (recommended) way to run a command in a "for each" semantic", that's a `for` loop, like you already wrote:

```
 for x in iterable:
     fn(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

> So in the provided scenario - is there a way to operate on a list like
> `dirs.remove_items(e for e in EXCLUDES if e in dirs)`

No. There is no built-in `remove_items` or `remove_all` function for lists. For sets, you have `intersection_update` or `-=` that does the job:

```
>>> EXCLUDES = {"a", "b", "c"}
>>> dirs = {"a", "x", "y"}
>>> dirs -= EXCLUDES
>>> dirs == {'x', 'y'}
True
```

> Or more generally: is there a (recommended) way to run a command in a "for each" semantic, like `fn(e) for e in container`

Yes: if `fn(e)` is pure, use a list comprehension, but else, write:

```
for e in container:
    fn(e)
```

**Some remarks**

**EDIT following @ShadowRanger comment below.**

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) states:

> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform walk() about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes walk() again. Modifying dirnames when topdown is False has no effect on the behavior of the walk, because in bottom-up mode the directories in dirnames are generated before dirpath itself is generated.

I didn't understand that the OP goal was to prune the search. The following remarks do not apply to this situation, but remain true in general. See @ShadowRanger's answer to prune the search using a slice assignment.

**END OF EDIT**

As you stated, it's a bad idea to use a list comprehension (or `map`) to produce a side effect. A list comprehension returns a list, period.

But nothing prevents you from assigning the list comprehension you wrote to `dirs` itself:

```
dirs = [e for e in dirs if e not in EXCLUDES]
```

You are not removing items but creating a new list (that's the point of list comprehensions if I'm not mistaken). If you are afraid of the cost of creating a new list, you can use a generator:

```
>>> EXCLUDES = {"a", "b", "c"}
>>> dirs = ["a", "x", "y"]
>>> dirs = (e for e in dirs if e not in EXCLUDES)
>>> dirs
<generator object <genexpr> at ...>
>>> list(dirs)
['x', 'y']
```

The generator is *lazy*, hence the elements will be read from `dirs` and filtered on the fly. No new list will be created. The same goes for `filter`:

```
>>> dirs = filter(lambda f: f not in EXCLUDES, dirs)
>>> dirs
<filter object at ...>
>>> list(dirs)
['x', 'y']
```

But not for `reduce`:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> dirs = reduce(lambda acc, f: acc if f in EXCLUDES else acc + [f], dirs, [])
>>> dirs
['x', 'y']
```

Comment: "But nothing prevents you from assigning the list comprehension you wrote to dirs itself" Actually, in this case, that doesn't work; the `dirs` produced by `os.walk` must be modified in-place to affect what gets walked on the next loop. Rebinding `dirs` to the result of a brand new `list` doesn't change the `list` hidden inside `walk` (which it provided an alias to in the initial binding of `dirs`). You can't do `dirs = [e for e in dirs if e not in EXCLUDES]` to modify the original `list`, but you can use slice assignment to do so, as noted in my answer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right, but the question is not so clear. "alter the generated list of directories in order to filter them" does not exactly mean prune the `os.walk` tree. I'll edit my answer.