# Python formatted list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python list l generated from text mining operation using python 3.x. The elements of the list l is displaying as

```
[[    1   2
  0  abc cde],
 [   1     2
  0  xyz, lmn pqr],
 [        1          2
  0  lwmnop  , xyz rmn],
```

l[0] is returning

```
[  1              2
 0  abc Schnittstelle]
```

and l[0][0] is representing

```
    1   2
0   abc cde
```

I want to get a formatted list from l & get only text. My output will look like below list

```
   [[  
      abc cde],
     [xyz, lmn pqr],
     [lwmnop  , xyz rmn],
```

Can you suggest how to get it?

Comment: You can check each item in the sublist whether it is of type string or not. Try using isinstance('a', str) for this.

Comment: You could filter the inners lists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623715/deleting-list-elements-based-on-condition

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have added 2 more code to understand l better

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Your list syntax is not correct.
There should be commas between the items.
And the text part should be in quotes.

To get a formatted list with only text, try the below code.

```
# input is a nested list
inp = [[    1,   2, 0,  'abc' 'cde'],[   1,     2, 0,  'xyz', 'lmn' 'pqr'],
[        1,          2, 0,  'lwmnop'  , 'xyz', 'rmn']]
out = list([item for item in nested_list if isinstance(item, str)] for nested_list in inp)
print(out)
# [['abccde'], ['xyz', 'lmnpqr'], ['lwmnop', 'xyz', 'rmn']]
```

What the code does is go through each item in the nested_list (which is a part of the input list) and check whether it is of type string or not. If it is, then the item is appended as a list to the output.